# D3 and mouse events, click test not working

Tags: javascript, onclick, d3.js

I am not sure why my click method is not working. In this test I want to be able to click on one of the circle nodes on the graph and display its number. Hovering over works kind of.

What library's click event am I using, D3? Jquery? normal JS?

ultimately I want to do tooltips when I hover over the nodes, and make them go away when I move the mouse away

http://jsfiddle.net/ericps/b5v4R/

```
dots.enter()
    .append("circle")
    //.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", complete_line.x())
    .attr("cy", complete_line.y())
    .attr("r",3.5)
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d){ return d.completed;})
    .on("click", function(d) { alert("hello"); });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've attached the event handler to svg:text element. I think you want to attach it to the svg:circle element:

```
dots.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", complete_line.x())
    .attr("cy", complete_line.y())
    .attr("r",3.5)
    .on("click", function(d) { alert("hello"); })
  .append("title")
    .text(function(d){ return d.completed; });
```

Comment: hey thanks! can you explain why that works? I am really missing some fundamentals on JS or Jquery that all the D3 stuff kind of assumes. Does append MEAN new object? Its kind of strange syntax

Comment: All the commands you chain with the dot notation are applied to the selection you are working on. Functions like select and append will change the active selection. So, the following will append one div element to the body, set the div's class, append a p element to the div, set the text contents of the p: d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "container").append("p").text("hey");. In your case you wanted the circle element to respond to mouse clicks and not the title element. That's why the "on" method had to appear before the append("title").

Comment: There are a lot of great tutorials: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials, for example http://www.dashingd3js.com/ and http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/ D3 does not rely on jQuery. It does assume some basic JS knowledge.

Comment: thanks! yeah all my JS knowledge has been pretty adhoc and mixed with jQuery out of necessity, so I will have to fill in all the gaps

Comment: @nautat hello, do you know how I can check if a selection has already been clicked? I am trying to make an interactive pie chart with D3 so when I click on a piece I want it do display a tooltip and if I click again on it or on another piece it should close it.